# FactoryBot and Faker - unique is not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, factory-bot, faker

I'm using FactoryBot and Faker for my tests, and it looks like that Faker is generating the same name:

```
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :nickname
  validates :nickname, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@example.org" }
    password "123456"
    trait :with_profile do
      profile
    end
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :profile do
    first_name Faker::Name.unique.first_name
    last_name Faker::Name.unique.last_name
    nickname { "#{first_name}_#{last_name}".downcase }
    user
  end
end

RSpec.feature "Friendships", type: :feature do
  scenario "User can accept a pending friendship request" do
    @tom   = create(:user, :with_profile)
    @jerry = create(:user, :with_profile)
    #other stuff
  end
end
```

Even I'm using the unique method, I'm getting the error

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Nickname has already been taken`.
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Should be:

```
first_name { Faker::Name.unique.first_name }
last_name { Faker::Name.unique.last_name }
```

When loading `Faker::Name.unique.first_name` will be evaluated. Threfore, use blocks.

Edit:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :profile do
    first_name Faker::Name.unique.first_name
  end
end
```

In this example `Faker::Name.unique.first_name` will be evaluated once, during the factory definition (when the file is loaded/required). If it finds a unique value, say 'John Doe' it's will be used for each item created by this factory.

Or in other words: after the file is loaded, and `Faker::Name.unique.first_name` evaluated you may think of this factory as if it was:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :profile do
    first_name 'John Doe'
  end
end
```

When you use blocks - the block's body will be evaluated each time you call `create(:profile)` or `build(:profile)`. The `Faker::Name.unique.first_name` part inside the block will be called each time, and return different, unique results.

Comment: Huge thanks! Could you just explain better why it wasn't working without the block?

Comment: FactoryBot separates attributes into static and dynamic. The best explanation of dynamic attributes is [here](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md#Dynamic_Attributes).

Comment: In te first example the `Faker::Name.unique.first_name` was evaluated once (during file loading) and each item created with this factory will get the (same) value it evaluated to. In the solution it is a block, and it's body is evaluated each time you create an item using this factory.